# Need to make JS wait for a CSS animation to be done before continuing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I am making an elevator simulator and everything works great except for the elevator not being able to keep up with my JS. The elevator moves to the right spot in the UI but the queue is processed so quickly that the elevator ends up right where it began in a blink of an eye. I have tried using timeouts and callbacks in order to make my function wait but I have had no success. **Each CSS animation takes 2 seconds to complete and the JS takes no time at all to run.**

Here is the JS:

```
// Start the Simulation
    let first_in_queue = queue_list.firstElementChild; // Grab first event in queue
    first_in_queue.classList.toggle('in-progress'); // Update UI to show user that the event is in progress

    let first_in_queue_information = first_in_queue.innerHTML.split('-'); // Parse for needed information
    let elevator_destination = Number(first_in_queue_information[1].charAt(8)); // Grab the events destination floor
    let elevator_from = Number(first_in_queue_information[0].charAt(7)); // Grab the events origin floor

    moveElevator(elevator_from);
    sleep(200);
    moveElevator(elevator_destination);



function sleep(miliseconds) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

     while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {}
}
```

This code does not work, all i get is a message in console saying "[Violation] 'click' handler took 201ms". I was not able to get the method to work using callbacks and after this solution did not pan out I thought to myself screw it, ask stack overflow.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: Yep, is there an easy Jquery solution?

Comment: Are aware of [CSS AnimationEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#Using_animation_events)?

Comment: I was not aware of animation events however someone else showed me that I can listen in JS for when a CSS animation ends. That seems to be working pretty well, thank you though for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect `transitionend` or `animationend` events

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/animationend_event

Comment: Thank you thank you, I did not know I could listen for animations to end. I have got it up and running pretty well thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQuery's `.ready()` but you need to include the CSS above your JS files.

Here is a reference for the function
https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: I am currently using the ready function, I surround all of the code in the js file with it creating an instantly invoked function expression, I hear it is good practice to do this. Is there a way for me to use it with a timeout sort of deal? How do you suggest I use it?

Comment: Where did you include your JS file in the HTML document?

Comment: I include the Jquery at the top via CDN and include a script tag for my local JS file at the bottom of the body.